# JavaFX How to set max/min window size?

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

Does `setMinSize()` work on containers such as `GridPane`, for example? I have found that in my program `GridPane` ignores min. size properties while resized manually.

Here is the FXML code:

```
<GridPane fx:id="gp" prefHeight="134.0" prefWidth="238.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="javafxapplication12.SampleController">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
</GridPane>
```

and the controller class

```java
public class SampleController implements Initializable {
    
    @FXML
    private GridPane gp;
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        gp.setMaxWidth(700);
        gp.setMinSize(200, 200);
    }
}
```

What's wrong here? Should there be some sort of a 'window' max/min size?

Comment: How are you adding that gridpane to the scene? The gridpane's parent layout container is important here. Some containers layout their children while others not.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I am going to assume that by window, you mean a [`Stage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html) (which subclasses `Window`).

The window size can vary from the root container size for the scene.  You can think of a window or stage as an independent viewport into the scene which can be sized larger or smaller than the min and max specifications of the scene root.

To set the minimum or maximum size of the Stage, set its [`minHeight`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#minHeightProperty) and [`minWidth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#minWidthProperty) or [`maxHeight`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#maxHeightProperty) and [`maxWidth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#maxWidthProperty) properties.

*Answers to additional questions*

> Can the `Stage` be set to "fit whole display" size?

[`stage.setFullScreen(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setFullScreen-boolean-)

> But how to make the size as same as we make size by clicking on the title bar?

[`stage.setMaximized(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setMaximized-boolean-)

Comment: Hi.  So may I set these stage values in the FXML file some place?  Is there a <stage> element for instance?

Comment: Can the Stage be set to "*fit whole display*" size?

Comment: that would be interesting @will

Comment: @will, call [stage.setFullScreen(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setFullScreen-boolean-) to "fit whole display".

Comment: But how to make the size as same as we make size by clicking on the title bar?